# How to merge 2 std::maps, and output the result in a 3rd map

Tags: c++, c++11

Editing the original question, as I wanted to ask question about `std::map`, instead of `std::vector`. My mistake. Sorry.

My data is actually in 2 `std::map`s. I want to merge both the maps into a 3rd map.

My first and second maps contain entries with the same key. So I would like to merge data under those keys as well, into my resultant 3rd map.

So if I use `std::merge`, will I be loosing data from the first or second maps common entries? As I have mentioned that there are common data (values) in both the maps?

Comment: [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)?

Comment: Are there any duplicates in the individual vectors?

Comment: After reading comments to another answer, I noticed that you did not ask about your real problem, but about method you attempted to solve it. This is commonly called [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please, edit question and include original problem. Merging two `std::map`s can be done much easier and faster.

Comment: Original question edited as suggested by Revolver_Ocelot

Comment: Updated my answer with new info

Comment: You need to make very clear what you mean by "common keys" (I changed the term to "common values".  Is it like `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`, where you want to merge both the upper level maps, and the vectors contained within the map that agree on the `std::string` key?  I edited your question to match that interpretation; please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @XMarshall: Please don't edit questions in ways that invalidate answers.  These people answered the question that you wrote.  If these didn't solve your issue, please create a _new_ question instead of editing to invalidate them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Info for sequential containers

If `vector`s (or other sequential containers like `list` or `deque`) are sorted, then you can use [`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union). There is an [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge), in case you want to save duplicates

**Code taken from linked page**:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    std::vector<int> v2 = {      3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; 
    std::vector<int> dest1;

    std::set_union(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                   v2.begin(), v2.end(),                  
                   std::back_inserter(dest1));

    for (const auto &i : dest1) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

### Info for associative containers

You can add unique keys to the `map` (or `set` and their unordered counterparts) using `insert` method. Any key already existing in original map will not be replaced (in `multiset` and `multimap` duplicate keys will be added, use `set_union` discussed before if this should be avoided).

**Example for map (ignoring entries with duplicate keys)**:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> v1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}};
    std::map<int, int> v2 = {                {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {6, 2}, {7, 2}};
    std::map<int, int> dest1 = v1;

    dest1.insert(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    for (const auto &i : dest1) {
        std::cout << i.first << ':' << i.second << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output (first number is the key, second — which map it comes from): **1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:2 7:2**

If you switch maps around (set `dest1` to be copy of `v2` at the beginning and inser values of `v1`), then output will be: **1:1 2:1 3:2 4:2 5:2 6:2 7:2**

**Example for multimaps (entries from both maps are preserved)**:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> v1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}};
    std::map<int, int> v2 = {                {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {6, 2}, {7, 2}};
    std::multimap<int, int> dest1 {v1.begin(), v1.end()};

    dest1.insert(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    for (const auto &i : dest1) {
        std::cout << i.first << ':' << i.second << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output: **1:1 2:1 3:1 3:2 4:1 4:2 5:1 5:2 6:2 7:2**

Notice that you cannot use `multimap` exactly the same way you use maps. For example, `operator[]` is unavaliable. You will need to use `insert` to add entries, and use `lower_bound` or `equal_range` member functions to extract entries.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it is a bit more complicated. I already have 2 maps complete with data. The key in the map is a string, and the corresponding data is an structure, which in turn contains some other data. Now, using the above approach, will my iterations in the map and applying business logic be efficient? The amount of data contained in both the maps is also very large. However, while processing the resultant 3rd and final map, I will be knowing the size of the first 2 maps.

Comment: @XMarshall , if your intent is to have a 3rd map filled with unique copies of data from first two maps without changing originals, then yes, It will be the most effective solution. If you do not care about content of the originals, you can simply insert second into first and if your data is move-enabled, iterate over your second map, moving content into first.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) is for:

```
std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
```

Comment: `std::merge` does not eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @AnonMail Please read the question exactly: "without duplicates"

Comment: I read it.  It's just not 100% clear what "without duplicates" is referring to.

Comment: Thanks. I made a big mistake while asking the question. My data is actually in 2 std::maps. Sorry for the mistake. So if I use std::merge, will I be loosing data from the first or second maps? There are common data (keys) in both the maps.

Comment: With `std::merge` you won't lose anything.  With `std::set_union` you will lose duplicates.  It's not clear which item is kept but if they truly are duplicates it shouldn't matter.  `std::set_symmetric-difference` won't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is something that both merges the maps, and *the contents* of the maps.

```
template<class Map, class Merge>
Map careful_merge( Map lhs, Map const& rhs, Merge&& merge ) {
  for (auto&& rhs_entry : rhs) {
    auto lhs_it = lhs.find(rhs_entry.first);
    if (lhs_it == lhs.end()) {
      lhs.insert( rhs_entry );
      continue;
    }
    auto& lhs_value = lhs_it.second;
    lhs_value = merge(std::move(lhs_value), rhs.second);
  }
  return lhs;
}
```

this is a helper function that takes two associative containers, and invokes `merge` if the value is in both containers.

Suppose you have a `std::map< std::string, std::vector<int> >` and wanted to merge them so that the result appends the mapped-to vectors.  Then:

```
using my_map = std::map< std::string, std::vector<int> >;
my_map a, b; // fill these somehow.
my_map result = careful_merge( a, b,
  [](std::vector<int> lhs, std::vector<int> const& rhs ) {
    lhs.insert(lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    return std::move(lhs);
  }
);
```

and we are done.

Entries that are unique in either the left or right hand side are never merged, just copied verbatim to the output.

Efficient move semantics are presumed.

It will work with both ordered and unordered maps.  It won't work with sets.  I'd advise against using it on multi maps, even if it works (I am uncertain) as it isn't designed for them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of **C++17** there is now a `std::map::merge(other_map)` method.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge